# my battle against web-server monitoring - slow server

Tags: mysql, monitoring

**Munin print-screen for reference**: http://img29.imageshack.us/i/munin.gif/

I monitor a web-server which basically runs apache+php+mysql.
No emails, no FTP, pure web-server.

The server is serving pages slow...

I think the bottleneck is MySQL configuration.

Quick Facts:

- most of queries are SELECTs, very few INSERTs and rare DELETEs
- mirror backup runs around 3AM - **represented by the red line** at the image provided
- I use **tuning-primer.sh** to help me adjust MySQL
- Server uptime is 26 days
- 2GB ram, Pentium(R) Dual-Core E5200 @ 2.50GHz, 7200 disk
- I have **log_slow_queries** enabled and **long_query_time = 1**
- Today I switched on the **log-queries-not-using-indexes**. That's why the slow-queries graph is displaying a peek

MyQSL tweaks I did on the **my.cnf**:

- join_buffer_size = 10M
- max_heap_table_size = 200M
- tmp_table_size = 300M
- init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8; SET CHARACTER SET utf8;'
- default-character-set = utf8
- character-set-server = utf8
- open_files_limit        = 2048
- ## log-queries-not-using-indexes
- key_buffer              = 256M
- max_allowed_packet      = 16M
- thread_stack            = 192K
- thread_cache_size       = 8
- ## max_connections        = 100
- table_cache             = 1024
- ## thread_concurrency     = 10
- query_cache_limit       = 4M
- query_cache_size        = 64M

Why yesterday and before everything was working OK? We didn't add new code or having a peek of visitors.

By looking at munin's graph do you see anything odd beside the slow-queries peek?

Do you recommend installing other tools in order to improve monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Number of processes has jumped, as has number of "Established" TCP connections (nearly 2x) -- I would track down the cause of those and see if it's related to the performance nosedive.

Comment: I ran **top -b -i -n 20 >> ./top_procs** to track the top process. Looks like apache was the problem. I raised apache configurations and the server is now responding very fast. **StartServers 25** and **Keepalive off** to web-services virtual hosts.